# How to insert multiple role in employee table using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm building API and I'm struggling with store data for multiple employee roles, how to store, could you provide me some example,
sorry for using the foreign language.
Karyawan=employee,
Jabatan=role

Karyawan.php

```
public function jabatan() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Jabatan','id_jabatan');
}
```

Jabatan.php

```
public function karyawan(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Karyawan','id_jabatan');
}
```

how to KaryawanController at store function should be...

[image: this is how its look like in front end]

[this is my model and controller](https://pastebin.com/rWVdHKwr)

i created my pivot table and i got this error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `tb_jabatan_karyawan` (`id_jabatan`, `id_karyawan`, `0`, `1`) values (0, 57, 1, 2))
ini controller sama modelnya..

Comment: Are you trying to select multiple roles and store it for a specific user?

Comment: yes, select multiple roles from web forms and store it..

Comment: so i created pivot table ,

Comment: It would help greatly to just stick with Laravel's default conventions, irrespective of your language. It helps. `Jabatan` primary key should be `jabatan_id`,  `Karyawan` primary key should be `karyawan_id`, Pivot table should be `jabatan_karyawan`

Comment: thanks for your advice.

Comment: ok, I have done the same thing for one of my projects. I am giving you the sample code. I'll be happy if it helps you.

Comment: That'd be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `User` and `Role` instead of  `Karyawan` and `Jabatan` respectively (sorry for that). `User` and `Role` has `Many-to-Many` relation because one `User` may have multiple `Roles` and vice versa.

**roles Table**

```
+----+------+-----------+
| id | role | timeStamps|
+----+------+-----------+
```

**role_user Pivot Table**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**Role Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function roles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

**RoleUser Pivot**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class RoleUser extends Pivot
{
    protected $table='role_user';
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','role_id'
    ];

    public static $role_attach_rules = [
        'roles' => 'required|array|min:1|exists:roles,id'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function role(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller Code for Assigning Roles to the User**

Here you will understand the methods by their names.

```
public function getAssignRole(){
    $users = User::all();
    $roles=Role::all();
    return View::make('assignrole', compact('users', 'roles'));
}

public function postAssignRole(Request $request){
    $attachvalidator = Validator::make($request->all(),RoleUser::$role_attach_rules);
    if ($attachvalidator->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($attachvalidator)->withInput();
    }
    $user=$request->get('user');
    $role=$request->get('roles');
    $attach = User::find($user)->roles()->attach($role);
    return 'Success';
}

public function detachRole(Request $request){
    $user=$request->get('user_update');
    $role=$request->get('roles_update');
    $attach = User::find($user)->roles()->detach($role);
    return 'detach Success';    
}
```

**View file (assignrole.blade.php) for Assigning Roles**

```
//This form is for assigning roles
<form method="post" action="{{route('role.assignrole.post')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
    <select id="user" name="user" class="select_with_style" required>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user['id']}}">{{$user['name']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select id="roles" name="roles[]" class="select_with_style" multiple="" required>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role['id']}}">{{$role['role']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit"/>
</form>

//This is for detaching roles from user
<form method="post" action="{{route('role.detach')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
    <select id="user_update" name="user_update" class="select_with_style"  required>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user['id']}}">{{$user['name']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select id="roles_update" name="roles_update[]" class="select_with_style" multiple="" required>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role['id']}}">{{$role['role']}}</option>
        @endforeach
     </select>
     <br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('role/assignrole', array('as' => 'role.assignrole', 'uses' => 'YourController@getAssignRole'));
Route::post('role/assignrole', array('as' => 'role.assignrole.post', 'uses' => 'YourController@postAssignrole'));
Route::post('role/detach', array('as' => 'role.detach', 'uses' => 'YourController@detachRole'));
```

Hope this helps.

> Edit

You can use [Voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) instead of doing this much work. It is very easy to understand and well structured and I think you will love it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes i'm already adding voyager in my composer and install it later, thanks for suggestion